# EXCEL: Match with either column

Tags: excel

My question: Can you build a Match formula so that it matches with either column A or B?

Process is a bit convoluted but will try to make it as clear as possible; maybe someone can come up with a better way to do this that doesn't even involve an index-match formula.

I have a data set that looks something like this:

> Match 1 // Team 1 // Team 2 // Winner: Team 1

> Match 2 // Team 1 // Team 3 // Winner: Team 3

I want to be able to track previous performances (i.e. team results in the last 4 matches for example), to be able to use that to predict the winner. To do so, I am building a table that looks something like this:

> Team 1 Match 1 // Result (0 or 1)

> Team 1 Match 2 // Result (0 or 1)

Problem is, to be able to tell whether or not Team 1 played in Match 1, I need to check 2 columns and I can't find anything on using match with an OR logic (have used it with an AND logic before).

I can think of some brute force solutions (like duplicating each match so that it only has 1 team and whether or not they won), but the problem is I have 20 thousand lines of matches and hundreds of different teams, so inefficiency destroys my computer. If you see a more elegant way of doing this I am all ears!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 2019 I think. Why?

Comment: 365 has extra formula for filtering data - something like `=IF(FILTER($D$1:$D$2,(B1:B2="Team 1")+(C1:C2="Team 1"),"")="Team 1",1,0)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a bit, I found a way of doing it, although its not particularly elegant. The pseudo formula:

=IF(match("Team 1"; column1;0) > match("Team 1"; column2;0); index(using column2); index(using column1))

Then it is a matter of using Indirect to make the range that is being checked start after the previous matched row.